# Upon build of documentation "related guides" section duplicates the link

Tags: documentation, paclets

On Mathematica 13.0 (built in paclet development tools) this input:

[image]

Produces this output:
[image]

Link to this notebook: https://github.com/Turak-Lab/disLocate/blob/main/debug/PlotPairCorrelationFunction.nb

Comment: With the information you provided, there is very little that this forum could do for you. You might want to provide a link to the notebook, or the specific input you had and how you entered it. If you think this is a bug, you should submit it to Wolfram Support.

Comment: @MarcoB I was just hoping that this is a "well known" issue to someone. I now posted the notebook link in the question. Thank you!